# Prolog: Adding elements to list through read/1

Tags: list, input, prolog

I am trying to add user input to a list with add_read_list/2 until the word "end." is encountered. This is how the output is supposed to look:

```
add_read_list(Resultlist, [a,b]).
|: c.
|: d.
|: e.
|: f.
|: end.
Resultlist = [f,e,d,c,a,b].
```

This is how far I have come:

```
 add_read_list(Resultlist,Entrylist) :- 
            read(end), append([], Entrylist, Resultlist).
add_read_list(Resultlist, Entrylist) :-
            read(Input), append([Input], Entrylist, X),
            add_read_list(Resultlist, X).
```

But this way every second input gets skipped:

```
add_read_list(Resultlist, [a,b]).
|: c.
|: d.
|: e.
|: f.
|: end.
Resultlist = [f,d,a,b].
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side-effects and Prolog do not go together very well. Why do you need this at all? Why not demand that the user writes, say: `p([f,d,a,b]).` in a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drop the first clause, and use the simple 'if/then/else' construct:

```
add_read_list(Resultlist, Entrylist) :-
  read(Input),
  (  Input = end
  -> reverse(Resultlist, Entrylist)
  ;  add_read_list(Resultlist, [Input|Entrylist])
  ).
```

instead of appending each item read, 'cons' it, and reverse the full list when done (well, simply unify to get the list in LIFO, as seems required. i.e. instead of `reverse(Resultlist, Entrylist)`, `Resultlist = Entrylist`)

Comment: @eva: Thus solution will loop or produce an error if `end.` is not provided

Answer (score 3):

The actual error is `read(end)`.   This will only succeed, if the term read in is `end`. Otherwise it fails.

But I do have a lot of reservation to tell you this at all, since nobody every does this is Prolog. Here are the actual things that would need improvement.

The first, is to use `end_of_file` in place of `end`, because this is automatically generated at the end of a file, plus you can write it yourself, too.

The second is the way how to handle this. You need to read and then process the term read in:

```
... read(X),  ( X == end_of_file -> ... ; /* whatever */ ... ), ....
```

However, please do reconsider your entire task. There is a single reason why this could be needed: When you are processing a Prolog file. But this you get cheaper and less error prone by saying `[file]`.

So better design your data to fit into Prolog terms.

Comment: Hello false, thank you for the answer and the good advice! I won't ever use this function if I have a read a file, I promise :) I had to write it as an exercise for a class I am attending...